# Adding a Class to <%=getCurrentAttribute

Tags: jsp

I'd like to add a class to this no in front of it. is there a way to do so?

```
<%=getCurrentAttribute('item', 'custitem_refurbmsg')%>
```

I'm thinking something like this here,

```
<%=getCurrentAttribute('item', 'custitem_refurbmsg') class='classname' %>
```

but this doesn't work. any idea's how to write this correctly?

Comment: And "this no" is ...?

Comment: More details are needed.  Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to ask great questions.  Great questions get better help from the community

Comment: netsuite sitebuilder customizing item/category template for single product page.

Answer (score 0):

The getCurrentAttribute tag outputs a value from Netsuite (and other server objects).  To style the output, you need to wrap it in HTML and add your class to that.

For example:

```
<div class="classname"><%=getCurrentAttribute('item', 'custitem_refurbmsg')%></div>
```